# Discrete subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$, find basis of vector space and integer such that subgroup can be expressed as linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X \neq \{0\}$ be a discrete subgroup of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$.

For an arbitrary $n \ge 1$, can we find a basis $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and an integer $0 < k \le n$ where $$X = \{n_1  c_1 + \cdots + n_kc_k,\text{ }n_1, \ldots, n_k \in \mathbb{Z}\}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_k=\min\{z\in \mathbb R:\ \exists x\in X\ \text{ such that }\ x_k=z\}.$ Since the coordinate functions preserve addition, the subset 
$$
X_k=X\cap\{(\overbrace{0,\ldots,0}^{k-1},t,0,\ldots,0):\ t\in\mathbb R\}
$$
is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$. Then $X_k=\mathbb Z\,z_k$. Now let $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ be the least positive integers such that $(m_1z_1,\ldots,m_nz_n)\in X$.

Now let $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\in X$. Since $p_k\in X_k$, we have $p_k=s_kz_k$  for some $s_k\in\mathbb Z$. Write the division algorithm, $$ s_k=q_km_k+r_k,$$ with $0\leq r_k<m_k$. Then
$$
(p_1,\ldots,p_n)=(q_1m_1z_1,\ldots,q_nm_nz_n)+(r_1z_1,\ldots,r_nz_n).
$$
Since $X$ is a group, we get that $(r_1z_1,\ldots,r_nz_n)\in X$. As $r_k<m_k$, it has to be that $r_1=\cdots=r_n=0$. It follows that all elements in $X$ are of the form 
$$
(q_1m_1z_1,\ldots,q_nm_nz_n)=q_1m_1(z_1,0,\ldots,0)+q_2m_2(0,z_2,0,\ldots,0)+\cdots+q_nm_n(0,\ldots,0,z_n).
$$
If some of the $z_k$ happens to be zero, we also get that $m_k=0$, and so we can put $z_k=1$ and the equality will not change. That way, the set 
$$
(z_1,0,\ldots,0),\ (0,z_2,0,\ldots,0),\cdots,(0,\ldots,0,z_n)
$$
is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.